# React+Next.js: cannot read properties of undefined when using onHandleDelete

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
    function DetailContainer() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
  const numbering = Number(id);
  const currentPostList = useRecoilValue(PostListState);

  const [postObj] = currentPostList.filter((post) => post.id === numbering); 
  const title = postObj.title;
  const content = postObj.content;
  const date = postObj.date;
  const postId = postObj.id;

  const setPostList = useSetRecoilState(PostListState);
  const onHandleDelete = (postId) => {
    setPostList(currentPostList.filter((item) => item.id !== postId));
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <div>{content}</div>
      <div>{date}</div>
      <Link href="/EditorPage">
        <button>Edit</button>
      </Link>
      <button>Remove</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I do not add onHandleDelete to Remove button, it works fine. But when I add onHandleDelete, error 'cannot read properties of undefined' appears. Is there a way that I can fix this so that I can delete postObj?

=> I fixed error by replacing to 'postObj?.title' since postObj has been removed when button was clicked

Comment: Can you show us how you're using `onHandleDelete` when it errors?

Comment: I fixed error by replacing to 'postObj?.title' since postObj has been removed when button was clicked

Answer (score 1):

What is postId? When you are filtering "currentPostList" it check for the all items whose ids are not equal to postId. Call onHandleDelete on Remove button and pass postId when calling.
Something like this:

```html
      <button onClick={() => handleDelete("paste postId here if you are getting it from props")>Remove</button>
```

it will work.

Comment: postId is id of postObj(which has id) and it does not work..

Comment: you already have postId declared on " const postId = postObj.id;" and when you are filtering you are using postId (this postId is argument of the function). so It is undefined. because you are not passing anything as parameters  when calling function. remove postId from argument of function (handleDelete).

Comment: const onHandleDelete = () => like this?

Comment: yes exactly like this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I fixed error by replacing to 'postObj?.title' since postObj has been removed when button was clicked